# Rewrite Rxjs 4 in Rxjs 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I rewrite this Rxjs 4 snippet in Rxjs 6?

```
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('.btn'), 'click').share();

click$
  .scan((a, b) => a + 1, 0)
  .bufferTime(4000, null, 3)
  .filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0)
  .concatMap(buffer => Rx.Observable.of(buffer).delay(1000))
  .timestamp()
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

https://jsbin.com/pacicubeci/1/edit?js,console,output

Here's my attempt:

```
import { $ } from "jquery";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { bufferTime, filter, scan, concatMap, timestamp } from "rxjs/operators";

const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($(".btn"), "click").share();

click$
  .scan((a, b) => a + 1, 0)
  .bufferTime(1000, null, 3)
  .filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0)
  .concatMap(buffer => Rx.Observable.of(buffer).delay(1000))
  .timestamp()
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

https://angularjs-g8w7z9.stackblitz.io

Comment: have you tried using this tool to guide you in the right direction? https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs-tslint install the package locally and run it, it will update all your streams, or at least try, then you can modify where needed

Comment: Just noticed you wrote v4 to v6, might still work

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for

```
const click$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(share());

click$
  .pipe(
    scan((a, b) => a + 1, 0),
    bufferTime(1000, null, 3),
    filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0),
    concatMap(buffer => of(buffer).pipe(delay(1000))),
    timestamp()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Operators are now in a `pipe`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-qczayg?file=app.js

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: We have one pitfall in your code, it will be applied for each click on page, not only to element with class btn

Comment: I didn't add because that can be written differently, depending on what they use. In Angular using `ViewChild` would be best (and replace `document` with `this.button.nativeElement`) but that might not work in every situation.